# Ingest Multiple CSV linked files in SOLR

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am new to SOLR, My problem is to link multiple CSV files linked together via single field in SOLR.
I have indexed a file of more than 5GB from CSV containing more that 250 fieds (**one field taxonomyid**) in document and querying it successfully,  
 now i have to add one more CSV file having fields (**taxonomyid, taxonomyvalue, description**) and link with the already indexed CSV file with the field taxonomoyid.
Kindly help me with the direction for what should i go for in SOLR R&D.